# Confusions with quadratic forms and basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a Euclidean finite-dimensional space. Let $Q(x)=\sum \limits_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}x_ix_j$ be a quadratic form on $V$.

We note that that we can write $Q(x)$ in this way $$Q(x)=X^TAX,$$ where $A=(a_{ij})$ is $n\times n$ matrix and $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$ is the column-vectors of coordinates of $x\in V$.

My question may sounds very stupid but let me ask it because I am very confused with this question:

Here $x_i$ are coordinates of $x\in V$, i.e. $x=\sum \limits_{i=1}^nx_ie_i$. But what is $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ here? I know that this is a basis of $V$ but is it some fixed basis or arbitrary basis or orthonormal basis?

I am agree that my question may sounds quite unclear but I would be happy if anyone can explain to me this from the scratch, please!

**EDIT:** Here is the source of my question: yesterday I have learnt some theory about that for any *symmetric* bilinear function $\mathcal{B}:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ there is an orthonormal basis such that the matrix of $\mathcal{B}$ is diagonal.

And I want to solve the following problem: Find an orthogonal transformation which reduces the following quadratic function to canonical form and find its canonical form: $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+4x_1x_2+4x_1x_3+4x_2x_3$.

Actually I know how to solve this problem but I was wondering in what basis this quadratic form is given?

Comment: It seems like you have some of the same concerns as did the poster of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3605473/265466).

Comment: @amd, I don't think so. I read that question and was not able to find what I need indeed.

Comment: Well, when you’re told that the definition of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$ is $T:(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+y,y-z)$, what bases do you assume there if they’re not explicitly mentioned?

Comment: @amd, good question. But to be honest i don't know probably in standard bases of $R^3$ and $R^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is not an orthonormal basis, the formula $Q(x)$ defines a quadratic form on $V$. That said, when $A$ is described as being "the" matrix associated with a quadratic form, the basis relative to which the quadratic form is defined is assumed to be orthonormal.

Comment: I will clarify my question very soon.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @ZFR It seems likely that in your question, $V$ is meant to specifically refer to $\Bbb R^3$ under the usual inner product. So yes, the formula is given relative to an orthonormal basis.

Comment: It is not so clear to me why the basis is supposed to be orthonormal. Btw, if the $Q(x)$ is given in basis which is not orthonormal then we cannot find orthogonal transformation, right? Probably i am misunderstanding all this.. oh God

Comment: @ZFR $V=\Bbb R^3$. $x$ is an element of $\Bbb R^3$. That is, $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. We don’t have to talk about any basis. If you want to write $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$, then $e_1,e_2,e_3$ need to be the standard orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes but we can write $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$ for any basis. I read the theory of bilinear functions and quadratic about 1-2 months ago and since then i am still confused with that question which i asked today. But to be honest i still cannot get the point

Comment: @ZFR if $V=\Bbb R^3$, then your comment is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me but what do you mean, please?

Comment: @ZFR If $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is an element of $\Bbb R^3$, then it is incorrect to say that "we can write $x = x_1e_1 + x_2 e_2 + x_3 e_3$ for any basis".

Comment: Yeah that's true! I am agree with you.. my bad. But I did not mean that. I meant that if $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is some basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in that basis, i.e. $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$ i.e. $x_i$ are coordinates of $x$ in some basis (not necessarily standard basis).

Comment: @ZFR sure, but when a formula describes $Q(x)$ in terms of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ (without first defining $x_i$), then the only reasonable assumption is that $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the standard presentation of $x$, i.e. the coordinate vector of $x$ relative to the standard basis.

Comment: Hmm sounds reasonable. Probably that's why in some books the authors say we'll assume that we are working with standard basis if otherwise not stated. (sorry for my bad English, please). Right?

Comment: @ZFR right ${}{}$

Comment: In that area of linear algebra namely quadratic forms I feel myself a bit uncomfortable

Comment: Also, when we are considering quadratic form $q(x)=\sum \limits_{i,j=1}^n q_{ij}x_ix_j$ then the matrix $Q=(q_{ij})$ is called the matrix of quadratic form $q(x)$ and $q(x)=X^TQX$. Is such $Q$ unique?

Comment: @ZFR If the $x_i$ refer to the coordinates relative to the standard basis, then there is a unique symmetric matrix $Q$ for which $q(x) = x^TQx$. A non-symmetric matrix $M$ will satisfy $x^TMx = x^TQx$ if and only if $\frac 12 (M + M^T) = Q$.

Comment: Since you are an expert in this field could you recommend some book which has good explanation about this. To be honest it really bothers since I cannot get some moments :(

Comment: @ZFR It seems as though most of your confusion stems from keeping things abstract rather than assuming or attempting the simplest framework, i.e. matrices and column vectors. Once you know how to do the important things with matrices, most things that one would try to do in the abstract vector space setting is a natural extension of something familiar. At least, that's how everything came together for me. I would recommend a matrix-heavy book such as "Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson or "Linear Algebra Done Wrong" by Sergei Treil.

Comment: Hi! Please sorry but maybe you can add something useful to this topic which confuses me a lot? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627745/coordinates-of-skew-symmetric-tensors